How to export GA3 custom variables with the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on
The Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on works fine for exporting page views, sessions, users, events, etc. However I also want to export my custom variables (key01-04 with value01-04). According to the API documentation one should use the following as dimensions: ga:customVarNameXX and ga:customVarValueXX
However the error Unknown dimensions(s): ga:customVarName01 keeps occurring.
Did anybody successfully export custom variables (i'm not talking about custom dimensions or custom metrics) with this add-on in Google Sheets?
